# R: locating files that their names contain a specific string from a directory and match to my list of wanted files

Tags: r, string-matching

It's me the newbie again with another messy file and folder situation(thanks to us biologiests): I got this directory containing a huge amount of .txt files (~900,000+), all the files have been previously handed with inconsistent naming format :(

For example, messy files in directory look like these:

```
ctrl_S978765_uns_dummy_00_none.txt
ctrl_S978765_3S_Cookie_00_none.txt
S59607_3S_goody_3M_V10.txt
ctrlnuc30-100_S3245678_DMSO_00_none.txt
ctrlRAP_S0846567_3S_Dex_none.txt
S6498432_2S_Fulra_30mM_V100.txt
.....
```

As you see the naming has no reliable consistency. What's important for me is the ID code embedded in them, such as S978765. Now I have got a list (100 ID codes) of these ID codes that I want.

The CSV file containing the list as below, mind you the list does have repetitive ID codes in the row due to different CLnumber value in the second columns:

```
ID code  CLnumber
S978765  1
S978765  2
S306223  1
S897458  1
S514486  2
....
```

So I want to achieve below task: find all the messy named files using the code IDs by matching to my list. And copy them into a new directory.

I have thought of use list.files() to get all the .txt files and their names, then I got stuck at the next step at matching the code ID names, I know how to do it with one string, say "S978765", but if I do it one by one, this is almost just like manual digging the folder.

How could I feed the ID code names in column1 as a list and compare/match them with the messy file title names in the directory and then copy them into a new folder?

Many thanks,
ML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
library(stringr)

# get this via list.files in your actual code
files <- c("ctrl_S978765_uns_dummy_00_none.txt",
           "ctrl_S978765_3S_Cookie_00_none.txt",
           "S59607_3S_goody_3M_V10.txt",
           "ctrlnuc30-100_S3245678_DMSO_00_none.txt",
           "ctrlRAP_S0846567_3S_Dex_none.txt",
           "S6498432_2S_Fulra_30mM_V100.txt")

ids <- data.frame(`ID Code` = c("S978765", "S978765", "S306223", "S897458", "S514486"),
                  CLnumber = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str_subset(files, paste(ids$ID.Code, collapse = "|"))
#> [1] "ctrl_S978765_uns_dummy_00_none.txt" "ctrl_S978765_3S_Cookie_00_none.txt"
```

`str_subset` takes a character vector and returns elements matching some pattern. In this case, the pattern is `"S978765|S978765|S306223|S897458|S514486"` (created by using `paste`), which is a *regular expression* that matches any of the ID codes separated by `|`. So we take `files` and keep only the elements that have a match in `ID Code`.

There are many other ways to do this, which may or may not be more clear. For example, you could pass `ids$ID.Code` directly to `str_subset` instead of constructing a regular expression via `paste`, but that would throw a warning about object lengths every time, which could get confusing (or cause problems if you get used to ignoring it and then ignore it in a different context where it matters). Another method would be to use `purrr` and `keep`, but while that might be a little bit more clear to write, it would be a lot more inefficient since it would mean making multiple passes over the files vector -- not relevant in this context, but possibly very relevant if you suddenly need to do this for hundreds of thousands of files and IDs.

Comment: thank you, I have tried the code and modified it to extract the full file names by using list.files and make the file names a matrix. the str_subset is awesome. However, now that I have a new matrix called "matched", which storing the str_subset, how do I copy and paste the actual files into a seperate directory?

Comment: haha, I have combined the file.copy suggestion from Ronak Shah and now it worked beautifully. Thank you guys!

Comment: And I really loved how you explained how the function works! Man you should get a YouTube channel

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex to extract the ID codes from the file name.

Here, I have used the pattern "S" followed by 5 or more numbers. Once we extract the ID_codes, we can compare them with the ones which we have in csv.

Assuming the csv is called `df` and the column name is `ID_Codes` we can use `%in%` to filter them.

We can then use `file.copy` to move files from one folder to another folder.

```
all_files <- list.files(path = '/Path/To/Folder', full.names = TRUE)
selected_files <- all_files[sub('.*(S\\d{5,}).*', '\\1', basename(all_files)) 
                                 %in% unique(df$ID_Codes)]
file.copy(selected_files, 'new_path/for/files')
```

Comment: thank you! Sorry I saw your post after the one above, but your file.copy suggestion actually could be used to connect to it to actually get the job done. Let me try it now.