# Cross referencing 10k+ file names with partial-name list, to isolate matching files

Tags: r, filenames, cross-reference

I am still very new to R (biologist learning the ropes) and hope someone might be able to help, please.
I have a folder of over 10k+ files each named "abc_Species name.filetype" eg. "abc_Panthera onca.filetype", "abc_Boa constrictor.filetype" etc. I need to isolate from that list of files the files that correspond to 1000 specific species-of-interest. So far I have performed the basics but am failing hard at cross-matching.

I have loaded various packages in order to try different solutions which I haven't been able to see through, and am no longer sure which are required! Here's what I have so far:

```
library(filesstrings)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
options(max.print=999999)

# Import file containing list of species of interest (among several columns, 
# the one titled "Species" is the column of my 1000 species-of-interest - 
# in that column are the list of Species names, most of which should be 
# found among the titles of the 10k+ files) 
Taxonomy <- read_csv("Taxonomy.csv")

#Create list of all of the 10k+ species files
Allspecieslist <- list.files(path = "C:/etc")
```

Several solutions that I have tried and failed (maybe just because I needed more of a walkthrough eg. [R: locating files that their names contain a specific string from a directory and match to my list of wanted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310309/r-locating-files-that-their-names-contain-a-specific-string-from-a-directory-an)) required me to copy-and-paste the whole list, which I couldn't do without creating a separate file first:

```
capture.output(Allspecieslist, file = "Allspecieslist.txt")
```

Is anyone able to help me with a code that will find all file names in the Allspecieslist that contain a species that is mentioned in the Taxonomy (i.e.species-of-interest) list? Once I have a list of the relevant matching files, I will create copies in a separate folder.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I get your question right. I'll be using fruits as example.

## Exact matching

Let's say your folder contains 10 files of fruits, and you wish to extract the file name of orange, dragon fruit and melon.

```
# this is your 10k files
Allspecieslist <- c("abc_apple.filetype", "abc_orange.filetype", 
                    "abc_grape.filetype", "abc_melon.filetype", 
                    "abc_mango.filetype", "abc_pear.filetype", 
                    "abc_watermelon.filetype", "abc_dragon fruit.filetype", 
                    "abc_kiwi fruit.filetype", "abc_durian.filetype")

# let's pretend these are your target species
Taxonomy <- data.frame(Fruit = c("orange", "dragon fruit", "melon"))

# google regex if you wish to know more about the matching patterns
output_list <- Allspecieslist[str_extract(Allspecieslist, "(?<=_).*(?=\\.)") %in% Taxonomy$Fruit]

[1] "abc_orange.filetype"       "abc_melon.filetype"       
[3] "abc_dragon fruit.filetype"
```

## Create list artificially

If you are sure that your target species are in your 10k files, you don't actually need to match them, you can just create a list to match the file name style.

```
prefix = ("abc_")
[1] "abc_"

suffix = (".filetype")
[1] ".filetype"

paste0(prefix, Taxonomy$Fruit, suffix)
[1] "abc_orange.filetype"       "abc_dragon fruit.filetype"
[3] "abc_melon.filetype"
```